# Rule rewrite does not work - nice urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried a lot. Switched a lot of flags, still does not work.

I need

```
http://www.wealthuniversity.eu/unsubscribe?id=87545783KQHWLUEGI79W
```

appear like

```
http://www.wealthuniversity.eu/unsubscribe/87545783KQHWLUEGI79W
```

what to do?

My code  is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(wealthuniversity\.eu)(:80)? 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.wealthuniversity.eu/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php [R=301]

RewriteRule   ^unsubscribe/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$   ^unsubscribe?id=$1

#and other things
```

Should there any flags, or something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wealthuniversity.eu$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.wealthuniversity.eu/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^\.]+)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule   ^/?unsubscribe/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /unsubscribe?id=$1 [NC,L]
```